# Implement LDAP Schema in an existing LDAP server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openldap

I have a schema file that has to be implemented with my existing LDAP server. Only thing I did was, just created the schema file.
Following is my schema file:

```
# userControl.schema
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.1 
    NAME 'attribute1'
    DESC 'gender'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.2
    NAME 'attribute2'
    DESC 'dateOfBirth'
    EQUALITY generalizedTimeMatch
    ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )

attributetype (1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.3
    NAME 'attribute3'
    DESC 'languages known'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype (  1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.4
    NAME 'attribute4'
    DESC 'motherTongue'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SINGLE-VALUE )


attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.5
    NAME 'attribute5'
    DESC 'nationality'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.6
    NAME 'attribute6'
    DESC 'worksAt'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.7
    NAME 'attribute7'
    DESC 'qualification'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.8
    NAME 'attribute8'
    DESC 'school'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.9
    NAME 'attribute9'
    DESC 'college'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )


attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.10
    NAME 'attribute10'
    DESC 'address'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )


attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.1.11
    NAME 'attribute11'
    DESC 'pinCode'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.*****.1.2.1
    NAME 'userControl'
    DESC 'RFC2798: New Customized Schema'
    SUP organizationalPerson
    STRUCTURAL
    MAY (
        gender $ dateOfBirth $ languagesKnown $ motherTongue $ nationality $ worksAt $ qualification $ school $ college $ address $ pinCode $ contactNumber $ interestedIn )
    )
```

What is the next step? How can I implement this schema? I am using Ubuntu 2.04.

Comment: Just include it in slapd conf.

Comment: inside schema_convert.conf???? Like  include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema ????

Comment: It would be worth a try don't you think? Instead of waiting for an answer here?